# Why is WordPress creating paginations for my single author pages?

Tags: wordpress

On a WordPress website which I have inherited from another development company, authors have pages which can be visited. Using Advanced Custom Fields each author has various fields to add content such as their image, bio, contact details etc.

The authors single page works as expected, pulling through all relevant information. The issue I am having is that these pages have somehow been paginated. **This means the same page has multiple URLs e.g website.com/author-name/ and website.com/author-name/page/2/**.

This issue flagged up in google search console as an error. If it helps, the website uses the 'User Role Editor' plugin and Yoast SEO (which is adding rel_next and rel_prev tags to the pages in question). I have already tried disabling these to see if they are causing the issue but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you look at the `author.php` template? Are the posts repeating on the second page? If the `author.php` template has the pagination functions, you can remove them.

Comment: Yes the article repeats on the second page. I have looked at the author.php template and can't see a pagination function.